# How can I rewrite a path from an addon domain to an external folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The structure is:

```
domain.com
   addon1.com
   addon2.com
   some_php_scripts_folder
      script.php
```

I want to rewrite a rule from addon1.com to script.php using relative path but I can't. (Bad request). Somehow it's logical because addon1.com it`s the root but i want to be relative ro the htacces file.

Ex:

```
RewriteRule ^page-example$ ../some_php_scripts_folder/script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a `RewriteRule` target outside of the document root, you'll need to create an alias in addon1.com's vhost config that's something along the lines of apache's [Alias directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html):

```
Alias /page-example /path/to/domain.com/some_php_scripts_folder/script.php
```